Should I drain the pierceable fuel canister once mounted to the stove?
Going to use a camping gas stove campingaz 206, which uses the pierceable fuel cartridge. The instruction on the cartridge states it should not be detached from the stove unless empty. Does it mean I have to burn it until the end? I’m planning to use it only for ~30min, so there would be still ~1.5h of burning time left.

No, you just close the valve and leave the cartridge attached to the burner. It can last for many years without leaking.

I've kept a camping gas cartridge burner for many years. I use it occasionally but one thing that might be a worry is if the rubber seal perishes and fails. This could be irrespective of whether the cartridge needs to be changed, because the seal is part of the burner. It's the orginal seal.

Sure, but fwiw the one I have looked ancient when I got it, 20-30 years ago, and still works fine (as of last year or something). Nothing has been done to the seal.

Thanks @TomasBy! Hope I can fix the valve properly, so that it doesn’t accidentally open in the backpack

I have detached a part used cartridge from the burner.
I did it in an open space, well away from any flame, and held it downwind of me as I detached it. The gas releases to the atmosphere, and the cartridge gets very cold from the pressure release. I then put it down and left it lying for a while, to let all the gas disperse.
The instruction not to do so is for safety reasons, so I advise you to follow the manufacturer's advice. There may also be an environmental impact. IDK whether it is 'greener' to release unburnt gas, or to burn it off.
Another problem with keeping the same burner for many years is that the rubber seal may perish. I have occasionally used the same burner for around 40 years without a problem, but I recommend that you do not do so, but follow the manufacturer's advice.

If you really need to empty it, I'd still recommend burning it off. CO2 is a less bad greenhouse gas than hydrocarbons (butane and/or propane) and it's safer

Actually, apparently, while methane is indeed a fairly potent greenhouse gas, propane and butane behave completely differently in this regard: their global warming potential is negligible. See e.g. https://naturalrefrigerants.com/ipcc-includes-gwps-for-hydrocarbons-in-new-report/
